# Access each key in array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I have the following array of hashes.

```
[{"comments_count"=>3, "like_count"=>341, "media_type"=>"IMAGE", "media_url"=>"https://url1.jpg", "permalink"=>"https://www.url.com", "timestamp"=>"2018-09-16T11:29:09+0000", "id"=>"17881817992270180"}, {"comments_count"=>1, "like_count"=>209, "media_type"=>"IMAGE", "media_url"=>"https://url2.jpg", "permalink"=>"https://www.url2.com", "timestamp"=>"2018-09-15T18:38:59+0000", "id"=>"17950602214183642"}]
```

I want to loop over each `media_url` like this:

```
Array.each do |media|
    media.media_url
end
```

But I get the following error:

```
undefined method `media_url' for Hash:0x00007fb987684d48
```

Comment: Cannot be reproduced. There is no method `Array.each`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `[]` to access hash values - it's not JS :)

```
a = [{"comments_count"=>3, "like_count"=>341, "media_type"=>"IMAGE", "media_url"=>"https://url1.jpg", "permalink"=>"https://www.url.com", "timestamp"=>"2018-09-16T11:29:09+0000", "id"=>"17881817992270180"}, {"comments_count"=>1, "like_count"=>209, "media_type"=>"IMAGE", "media_url"=>"https://url2.jpg", "permalink"=>"https://www.url2.com", "timestamp"=>"2018-09-15T18:38:59+0000", "id"=>"17950602214183642"}]
a.each {|h| h['media_url']  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could refer to the values of specific key, by using `.fetch()` method on the Hash.

```
arr = [{"comments_count"=>3, "like_count"=>341, "media_type"=>"IMAGE", "media_url"=>"https://url1.jpg", "permalink"=>"https://www.url.com", "timestamp"=>"2018-09-16T11:29:09+0000", "id"=>"17881817992270180"}, {"comments_count"=>1, "like_count"=>209, "media_type"=>"IMAGE", "media_url"=>"https://url2.jpg", "permalink"=>"https://www.url2.com", "timestamp"=>"2018-09-15T18:38:59+0000", "id"=>"17950602214183642"}]

arr.each {|h| h.fetch('media_url') }
```

in case key has not been found in some of the hashes, can specify default value:

```
arr.each {|h| h.fetch('media_url') { 'https://default_url.jpg' } }
```

To directly return an output as an Array of links, you can simply use `.map()` instead:

```
arr.map {|h| h.fetch('media_url') { nil } }
```